# How do I get the contents from an aria-label from an html file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

From everything I read it mentions using the class or other identifiers to access the text but I cant find a way strictly using the aria label. I'm new to both python and web scraping. Any help would be appreciated. I would use the class but it seems to change game to game, unless I temporarily save it. Not sure what makes the most sense, but seeing if there is an easier way.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cN1V.png)

I tried

```
    f = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"aria-disabled": "true"})
    f = soup.find_all('aria-label')
```

I get empty arrays

Answer (score 0):

Beep..Bop...boop..

Use a `CSS selector` to find elements with a specific aria-label attribute.(Copy CSS selector to label from chrome dev tools)

```py
# you shd Find the div element with the aria-label attribute
div_element = soup.find('div', {'aria-label': True})

# Get the content of aria-label attribute
aria_label_content = div_element['aria-label']

print(aria_label_content)
```